# NSString Comparison Issue in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Here's the code:

```
NSString *decryptResponseString = [AESCrypt decrypt128:responseString key:@"a16byteslongkey!"];        
NSString *lisence = [NSString createLisence:self.serial withSalt:sha_salt];
NSLog(@"lisence: %@", lisence);
NSLog(@"decrypt: %@", decryptResponseString);
int a = [lisence isEqualToString:decryptResponseString]?1:0;
NSLog(@"%i", a);
```

Here's the log:

> 2012-12-16 15:52:30.249 TextLabelButton[1430:11303] lisence: 3b27cde24235d08a5de5904a4
>       2012-12-16 15:52:30.250 TextLabelButton[1430:11303] decrypt: 3b27cde24235d08a5de5904a4
>       2012-12-16 15:52:30.250 TextLabelButton[1430:11303] 0

I don't know why the result is always "0" when I use `[lisence isEqualToString:decryptResponseString]` or `(lisence == decryptResponseString)`.

Comment: Are you sure they are the same? no extra spaces?

Comment: yeah, i'll check right now

Comment: I don't know why when i check the length of two string, there're different:                                                      2012-12-16 16:19:43.970 TextLabelButton[1478:11303] length of lisence: 25
2012-12-16 16:19:43.970 TextLabelButton[1478:11303] length of decrypt: 32

Comment: length of lisence: 25, and length of decrypt: 32 ?

Comment: What library are you using for your AESCrypt? Have you tried https://github.com/Gurpartap/AESCrypt-ObjC?

Comment: you likely use it wrong. strings with length 25 is definitely not equal to 32 ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would check that the string lengths are the same.

If they are not, if there are spaces at either end, then that's down to your string generation functions.

If you want to get rid of leading and trailing strings use NSString's methods, for example

```
NSString *trimmedString = [strimToTrim stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whiteSpaceCharacterSet]];
```

You can read the docs for it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/whitespaceCharacterSet)

Comment: @TruongHo try using [[NSCharacterSet alphaNumericCharacterSet]invertedSet] as the argument to stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: and see if that works. This will trim off anything but numbers and letters (in case there are non-printing characters in your string).

Comment: Thank you, I've solved the issue, I think the different between two strings due to the AESCrypt I used. So I change both of two into char *, then compared it:                                            const char * lisence_str = [lisence UTF8String];
const char * decrypt_str = [decryptResponseString UTF8String];          And use strcmp(lisence_str, decrypt_str) to compare if they're different. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

a workaround for get rid of spaces:

```
id trimmedDecrypt = [decrypt stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]; 
BOOL r = [license isEqualToString:trimmedDecrypt];
```